# canvas not rendering image using react-creact-app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas, create-react-app, drawimage

I am currently using create-react-app along with canvas api to render an image. I am unable to do so. I am not sure what since happening everything seems to be correct but im not sure why the image is not showing up. I've checked the image so i remove display none the image shows up.

```
import generatorImage from './generator.jpg';

const Canvas = props => {

const canvasRef = useRef(null);
const imgRef = useRef(null);

useEffect(() => {
  const canvas = canvasRef.current;
  const img = imgRef.current;
  const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  
  img.onload = () => {
    context.drawImage(img,10,10);
    context.font = "40px Courier";
    context.fillText('hello world', 0, 75);
  }
  

}, []);

return (
<>
  <canvas ref={canvasRef} style={{border:`1px solid black`}} height={cargoHeight}/>
  <img ref={imgRef} src={generatorImage} alt='cargotype' style={{display: 'none'}} />
</>
  )
```

}

Comment: I have same issue... caan't see image being rendered on the canvas. So, in my case I do initial rendering using the useEffect() hook once and later do dynamic rendering as I need to embed user text on top of the image. I'm using React 18. Did you manage to solve this? In my Chrome developer console, I can see the canvas element without the end tag </canvas>